# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::only_full_group_by()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am working in laravel 5.3. I  have issue to run query.I am trying for groupby query but its not working and error like Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::only_full_group_by(). My code like

```
public function showcart()
{

        $cart = DB::table('cartshow')->only_full_group_by('pro_id')->get(); die();

        $i = 1;
        foreach($cart as $tt)
        {

            $count = DB::table('cartlist')->where('pro_id',$tt->pro_id)->sum('qnty');

            $sel_pro= DB::table('product') -> where('id',$tt->pro_id)->first();

            $proname = $sel_pro->name;
            $price = ($sel_pro->price) * $count;

      echo $cartdata  ="<tr>
                                <td>$proname<br><small>Swaminarayan, Extra Hot, Cheese</small></td>
                                <td style='vertical-align:middle'>
                                <input type='button' value='-' onclick='qtyminus($tt->pro_id);' class='qtyminus' field='quantity' />
                                <input type='text' name='quantity' value='$count' class='qty' id='txt$tt->pro_id'/>
                                <input type='button' value='+' onclick='qtyplus($tt->pro_id);' class='qtyplus' field='quantity' />
                                </td>
                                <td class='text-right' style='vertical-align:middle'><button data-id ='$tt->pro_id' type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-info'><i class='fa fa-remove'></i></button></td>
                            </tr>";

    }   

}
```

Comment: I'm not able to find any `only_full_group_by` method in Laravel, am I missing something ? Can you post the reference to your method ?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by

Comment: you can not use the method like this. Laravel QueryBuilder does not have that method defined.Since, your link points to **version 5.7** `only_full_group_by` is default. So, instead use `groupBy()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`only_full_group_by` is one of the MySQL modes. You can not call `only_full_group_by` on the **QueryBuilder** since there isn't any `only_full_group_by` method  defined in **QueryBuilder**.
Yo use **Group By** in Laravel use `groupBy()` method.

```
$cart = DB::table('cartshow')->groupBy('pro_id')->get();
```

Since, in comments you have provided the [MySQL link of version 5.7](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) `only_full_group_by` is the default mode.

If you want to manipulate the MySQL modes here's the [reference](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/strict-mode-and-other-mysql-customizations-in-laravel-5-2)

Comment: If I am using groupby i got that erroor..QLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'hotel.cartshow.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select * from `cartshow` group by `pro_id`)

Comment: @vjBDT disable the strict mode in your connections by using `'strict' => false,` in your `config/database.php`